# General 4x4 matrix belonging to SU(4) group

Tags: matrices

I am looking for the general form of SU(4) matrix.

I believe the answer lies in section 3 or section 4 of the following link : http://arxiv.org/pdf/0802.2634v1.pdf

PS : I don't quite understand Lie Algebra and Group theory in detail and need this for addressing a different problem in my field.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.ejtp.com/articles/ejtpv10i28p9.pdf

Comment: Obviously, in order to answer this you will have to know what "SU(4)" means!  SU(4) is the set of "special unitary 4 by 4 matrices".  Here "special" means it determinant is 1.  "Unitary" means that it conjugate transpose (uij is equal to the complex conjugate of uji) is equal to its inverse.

Comment: @AJStas Thank you for the link. Can you please explain/ tell me about some resource which explains how to obtain the general parametrization form from the generators? For example : In the case of SU(2) the general form is : ((alpha, beta*),(-beta,alpha*))

Comment: @user247327 Thank you for the response. I do understand this much. However I do not understand how to get the general parameterized form given these properties and the generators of the group.

Comment: This might help: http://www.ejtp.com/articles/ejtpv10i28p9.pdf

Comment: This link it's already in the first comment....

Comment: If anyone lands here - this is a good reference to generate random unitaries (typically for studies in quantum computing)  :
https://chaos.if.uj.edu.pl/~karol/pdf/ZK94.pdf